# var/www/html past file is not working

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, ubuntu-14.04

I am totally new in Linux. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and installed lamp also phpmyadmin. When I create any file or folder in

> var/www/html

that time everything works fine. But when I past any folder or file from wamp that time that file is not working. I don't know the problem . actually I have few projects on wamp and I wanna transfer all project to lamp . now can any-one tell me that how to do it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using ubuntu linux

Comment: Please can you define exactly what "doesn't work" means in this context

Comment: if i copy any php, html file or folder (example: 01.php )and past into var/www/html and then if i hit my ip address in the browser (example : http://137.0.2.2/01.php) that time i got (404 Not Found).but if i create any file in the var/www/html (example : 02.php) and then if i browse it that time its work .

Comment: How do you copy the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a permission to that folder. 
In you command terminal write the following.

//This gives you permission for that folder and all its contents.

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 /www/html Or
```

Alternatively you can  first change to your development directory

```
  cd /var/www

   sudo chmod -R 777 html
```